# mailgunjs webhook post forwarding route req.body['attachment-count'] === 1 but no url

Tags: express, attachment, mailgun, multer

I have set a mailgun webhook post forwarding route and the request attachment-count comes in with a value of 1, but the request body nor the header contains a url.

I'm using express and multer (new multer().any()) as well as body-parser as express middleware.

Not finding any issues discussing a missing url.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the files are in req.files for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem.

Happy to close if duplicate issue exists.